# having trouble with loops in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

im working on seeding a procedural generated map but when i go to run it it just does work in the background when it is supposed to show a map with different colored squares. The method i need help with picks a few random locations on the map and assigns a random type as a starting point.

here is the entire method

```
public void seed(){//seeds the map
double seedNum = (mapWidth*mapHeight*.02);//determine number of seed positions needed
if((int)seedNum < 1){//will always seed at least 1 square
  seedNum = 1;
}

int seedListX[]= new int[(int)seedNum];//list of seeded coordinates to check for dupilcates
int seedListY[]= new int[(int)seedNum];

int seedX = (int)Math.random()*mapWidth;
int seedY = (int)Math.random()*mapHeight;
seedListX[0] = seedX;
seedListY[0] = seedY;

for(int i =1; i < (int)seedNum; i++){
  int error = 0;
  seedX = (int)Math.random()*mapWidth;
  seedY = (int)Math.random()*mapHeight;
  seedListX[i] = seedX;
  seedListY[i] = seedY;

   for(int j = 0; j < seedNum;j++){//goes through seed coordinates list to check for duplicates
    if(seedX == seedListX[j] || seedY == seedListY[j]){
      error = 1;
    }
  }

  int type = (int)Math.random()*5+1;//choose random type

  if(error != 1){
    this.setType(seedX,seedY,type);
  }else{
    i--;
  }//end inner loop
}
}//end outer loop
```

I tested the code and it worked fine once I removed this block

```
for(int j = 0; j < seedNum;j++){//goes through seed coordinates list to check for duplicates
    if(seedX == seedListX[j] || seedY == seedListY[j]){
      error = 1;
    }
  }

  int type = (int)Math.random()*5+1;//this line is fine

  if(error != 1){
    this.setType(seedX,seedY,type);
  }else{
    i--;
  }//end inner loop
```

Im sure its an infinite loop but i am not seeing it, any help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: check the closing brackets of the loop

Comment: also when i run it without the smaller code block it always sets the very first square to type 1, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening everytime

```
else{
  i--;
}
```

so the `for` loop will never increment and finish

Maybe when you do (occurs everytime so check that `i != j`)

```
error = 1;
```

you want to break

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j = 0; j < seedNum;j++){//goes through seed coordinates list to check for duplicates
    if(seedX == seedListX[j] || seedY == seedListY[j]){
      error = 1;
    }
}
```

For `i == j` the condition will always yield `true`(because `seedX == seedListX[i]` and `seedY == seedListY[i]`) - you are colliding with yourself...

Also, you really shouldn't check for collisions with seed coordinates you haven't filled yet.

Let's say `seedNum = 2`. First iteration you create the first seed:

```
i: 0
seedListX: [12, #JUNK#]
seedListY: [34, #JUNK#]
seedX: 12
seedY: 34
```

Now, in the first iteration of the inner loop:

```
j: 0
seedListX[j] == seedListX[0] == 12 == seedX
seedListY[j] == seedListY[0] == 34 == seedY
```

The problem is clear - you are comparing the first coordinate with the first coordinate - of course they will collide!

**But** - there is another problem. Let's look at the second iteration of the inner loop:

```
j: 1
seedListX[j] == seedListX[1] == #JUNK#
seedListY[j] == seedListY[1] == #JUNK#
```

`#JUNK#` will happen to be `0`, because that's how Java initializes things, but it's still a junk - it contains an arbitrary(although determinant) value, **not** the actual coordinate of the second seed(which was not yet created!)

You should only check collisions with seeds created in the previous iterations:

```
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //...
```